# Test-particles motion in general space-time with *torsion* : geodesics or auto-parallel curves?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, field-theory, curvature

Consider a general curved space-time with *torsion*.  In the standard Einstein-Cartan-Kibble-Sciama theory (ECKS or ECSK), torsion is non-dynamical and doesn't propagates in free space.  But a more general theory could allow torsion to be dynamical and propagates.  In general, *geodesics* (the shortest or extremal length curves) and *auto-parallels* (the *straightest* curves) are different curves in space-time.

In classical general relativity (without torsion), test-particles without spin should follow geodesics.  This is a statement of inertia motion.

But with torsion, what curve should a test-particle follow ?  A geodesic or a auto-parallel curve ?

It can be shown that if torsion is *totally antisymetric* (which is just a special case), geodesics and auto-parallel curves are the same.  But in general they aren't.

I feel that Newton's inertia principle is really about the *straightest* curves, and not the *shortest* (or extremal) curves.

Is there any indication, clue or argument, that the *spineless* test-particles should follow **auto-parallel curves** in space-time, instead of geodesics ?  Would it be more natural in some way ?

If the auto-parallel curves are more fundamental (from an **inertia** point of view), then would it imply that the lagrangian method for fields is falling apart as a general principle, since it's (i.e. was) motivated by the inertia principle ?

Comment: Isn't the variational principle related to the shortest proper time, assuming the curve on the space-time manifold is parametrized by proper time? This variational principle should replace whatever principle occurring in Newtonian mechanics (Newton's inertial principle holds for motion in a 0 vector total field of forces, and this is unrelated to notions of "straightest" or "shortest" curves).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81753/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318200/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342821/2451

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this identical question has been asked here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318200/

Comment: @Dvij: that's not what off-topic means: it could be marked as a duplicate, but even that is problematic as the question it is a duplicate of has no anwers

Comment: @Christoph I agree. But there is a bug in the StackExchange network which prevents one to do so in certain cases. See: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9949/

Comment: Yes, the question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318200/ is actually very similar to mine.  But there's already an interesting answer given below, for my own formulation of the question.

Answer (score 4):

My vote would go to the auto-parallels as well, which seems to me the correct generalization of the idea that bodies should persist in their state of motion.

According to Kleinert, Pelster ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1026701613987), [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9605028)), due to the [closure failure of parallelograms](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270284) in spaces with torsion, the action principle needs to be modified, leading to the appearance of an additional torsion term in the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q^\lambda(\tau)} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q^\lambda(\tau)} = 2S_{\lambda\mu}{}^\nu(q(\tau)) \dot q^\mu(\tau) \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q^\nu(\tau)}
$$

Comment: The arguments from the paper cited in your answer are pretty strong and convincing :  **inertia** and **locality** imply that a spinless particle should follow an auto-parallel curve, instead of a geodesic.  From the paper : "*Because of its inertia, a particle will change its direction in a minimal way at each instant of time, which makes its trajectory as straight as possible. If it were to choose a path which minimizes the length of the orbit it would have possessed some global information of the geometry.*"

Answer (score 0):

Without prejudicing the issue on either side, we can follow the Gandalf / Toucan Sam Strategy and follow our nose.

The matter can be addressed by applying the continuity equation to the stress tensor density for the particle:
$$^μ_ν(x) = \int_{-∞}^{+∞} p_ν(s) v^μ(s) δ(x - x(s)) ds, \hspace 1em v^ρ(s) = \frac{dx^ρ}{ds},$$
with the momentum vector being given by:
$$p_ν(s) = m g_{μν}(x(s)) v^μ(s),$$
where $m > 0$ is the mass of the particle, and $s ↦ x(s)$ its worldline with parameterization, $g_{μν} v^μ v^ν = 1$; i.e. $s$ is the proper time, if the convention is chosen of setting $g_{00} = 1$ in the Minkowski limit.

The divergence can be tabulated as follows:
$$\begin{align}
∂_μ^μ_ν(x)
&= \int_{-∞}^{+∞} p_ν(s) v^μ(s) ∂_μ δ(x - x(s)) ds \\
&= \int_{-∞}^{+∞} p_ν(s) \left(-\frac{d}{ds} δ(x - x(s))\right) ds \\
&= -\left[p_ν(s) δ(x - x(s))\right]_{-∞}^{+∞} + \int_{-∞}^{+∞} \frac{dp_ν}{ds} δ(x - x(s)) ds \\
&= \int_{-∞}^{+∞} \frac{dp_ν}{ds} δ(x - x(s)) ds
\end{align}$$

Now ... the continuity equation is for the stress tensor:
$$∇_μT^μ_ν ≡ ∂_μT^μ_ν - Γ_{μν}^ρ T^μ_ρ + Γ_{μρ}^μT^ρ_ν = 0.$$
The Levi-Civita connection is $Γ_{μν}^ρ - C_{μν}^ρ$, where $C_{μν}^ρ$ is the contorsion, or just $Γ-C$ for short. A well-known (to General Relativists) identity for it is given by:
$$(Γ-C)_{μρ}^μ = \frac{1}{2} g^{μν} ∂_ρ g_{μν} = \frac{∂_ρ \sqrt{|g|}}{\sqrt{|g|}}.$$
Applying this to the continuity equation:
$$∂_μT^μ_ν + \frac{∂_ρ \sqrt{|g|}}{\sqrt{|g|}}T^ρ_ν - Γ_{μν}^ρ T^μ_ρ + C_{μρ}^μT^ρ_ν = 0,$$
multiplying by $\sqrt{|g|}$, and noting that the stress tensor density, itself, is given by $^ρ_ν = \sqrt{|g|}T^ρ_ν$, we can write:
we get:
$$∂_μ^μ_ν - Γ_{μν}^ρ^μ_ρ + C_{μρ}^μ^ρ_ν = 0.$$

Upon substitution, we get:
$$
0 = \int_{-∞}^{+∞} \left(\frac{dp_ν}{ds} - Γ_{μν}^ρ(x) p_ρ(s) v^μ(s) + C_{μρ}^μ(x) p_ν(s) v^ρ(s)\right) δ(x - x(s)) ds \\
\int_{-∞}^{+∞} \left(\frac{dp_ν}{ds} - Γ_{μν}^ρ(x(s)) p_ρ(s) v^μ(s) + C_{μρ}^μ(x(s)) p_ν(s) v^ρ(s)\right) δ(x - x(s)) ds.
$$

We assume that there is a foliation of the space-time manifold - at least in the vicinity of the worldline - into spacelike 3-surfaces $Σ_s$, such that (1) $x(s) ∈ Σ_s$ for each $s ∈ (-∞,+∞)$ and (ii) we can decompose the delta function into $δ(x_s - x(s')) = δ_{Σ_s}(x_s - x(s))δ(s - s')$. Then an integral of the following form may be worked out as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{Σ_s} \left(\int_{-∞}^{+∞} F(s') δ(x_s - x(s')) ds'\right) dx_s 
&= \int_{Σ_s} \left(\int_{-∞}^{+∞} F(s') δ_{Σ_s}(x_s - x(s))δ(s - s') ds'\right) dx_s \\
&= \int_{-∞}^{+∞} F(s') \left(\int_{Σ_s} δ_{Σ_s}(x_s - x(s)) dx_s\right) δ(s - s') ds' \\
&= \int_{-∞}^{+∞} F(s') δ(s - s') ds' \\
&= F(s).
\end{align}$$

Applying this to the reworked continuity equation, we get:
$$\frac{dp_ν}{ds} - Γ_{μν}^ρ p_ρ v^μ + C_{μρ}^μ p_ν v^ρ = 0,\label{1}\tag{1}$$
where all $x$-dependent quantities are evaluated on the worldline at $x(s)$. The first two terms are the momentum-space version of the terms that appear in the geodesic and autoparallel equations:
$$\frac{dp_ν}{ds} - Γ_{μν}^ρ p_ρ v^μ = m g_{μν} \left(\frac{dv^μ}{ds} + Γ_{νρ}^μ v^ν v^ρ\right). \label{2}\tag{2}$$
This requires on that the connection $Γ$ be metrical and involves the chain rule on $g_{μν}(x(s))$ in $p_ν = g_{μν}v^μ$, along with the metrical property of the connection:
$$
\frac{dp_ν}{ds} = m\left(\frac{dg_{μν}}{ds} v^μ + g_{μν} \frac{dv^μ}{ds}\right), \hspace 1em
\frac{dg_{μν}}{ds} = ∂_ρ g_{μν} v^ρ = \left(g_{σν} Γ_{ρμ}^σ + g_{μσ} Γ_{ρν}^σ\right) v^ρ \\
⇒ \frac{dp_ν}{ds} = m\left(g_{σν} Γ_{ρμ}^σ + g_{μσ} Γ_{ρν}^σ\right) v^ρ v^μ + m g_{μν} \frac{dv^μ}{ds}.
$$
We can rewrite
$$Γ_{μν}^ρ p_ρ v^μ = Γ_{ρν}^σ p_σ v^ρ = m g_{μσ} Γ_{ρν}^σ v^μ v^ρ.$$
Therefore, upon cancellation, we get:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dp_ν}{ds} - Γ_{μν}^ρ p_ρ v^μ
&= m g_{σν} Γ_{ρμ}^σ v^ρ v^μ + m g_{μν} \frac{dv^μ}{ds} \\
&= m g_{μν} \frac{dv^μ}{ds} + m g_{μν} Γ_{ρσ}^μ v^ρ v^σ \\
&= m g_{μν} \left(\frac{dv^μ}{ds} + Γ_{ρσ}^μ v^ρ v^σ\right).
\end{align}$$

Rewriting the contorsion term in ($\ref{1}$),
$$C_{μρ}^μ p_ν v^ρ = -p_ν N = -m g_{μν} N v^μ, \hspace 1em N = -C_{σρ}^σ v^ρ,$$
divide out the mass $m > 0$:
$$
g_{μν} \left(\frac{dv^μ}{ds} + Γ_{ρσ}^μ v^ρ v^σ - N v^μ\right) = 0
$$
and invert the metric in $g_{μν}$ to get:
$$\frac{dx^μ}{ds} = v^μ, \hspace 1em \frac{dv^μ}{ds} + Γ_{ρσ}^μ v^ρ v^σ = N v^μ. \tag{3}$$

That's a variation of the auto-parallel equation, but with the need to reparametrize $s$. If you reset the parameter to $S$, such that
$$\frac{d}{ds}ln\left(\frac{dS}{ds}\right) = N = -C_{σρ}^σ v^ρ, \tag{4}$$
then you'll get:
$$\frac{dx^μ}{dS} = v^μ, \hspace 1em \frac{dv^μ}{dS} + Γ_{ρσ}^μ v^ρ v^σ = 0. \tag{5}$$

There's a warping of some sort on the proper time $s$ into $S$.

The contorsion is warping the time.

I did these calculations extemporaneously. You should check it closely. It needs a once-over. I might try it again at a later time. I'm pretty sure of ($\ref{1}$) and ($\ref{2}$) is fairly standard and well-known.