# Which geodesics light travels on: metric or affine in Einstein-Cartan theory?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, geodesics, modified-gravity

In a generic Lorentzian spacetime solving the Einstein equations since both the metric and affine geodesic coincide this question doesn't arise. But in the Einstein–Cartan theory it is not very obvious as the metric geodesics and the affine geodesics are not the same thing. So how do we decide on which geodesic will the light travel on?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81753/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318200/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342821/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362273/2451

Comment: [Also related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503518).